# Hover underline not showing

Tags: html, css, underline

I am trying to create a navigation bar with underline effect under each element when hovering over. For some reason the hover effect does not show up and I don't know if it's my code that's wrong or the browser and I have no idea how to fix it. The problem is the *".underline_indicators"* class

I am following the latest freeCodeCamp course for creating a web design system, followed the code exactly but it still did not work. Any help is much appreciated!

Here's my code snippet:

```css
 ul{
        display: flex; 
        list-style: none;
    }

    a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .underline-indicators > * {
        padding: 1rem;
        border: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: .2rem solid white;
    }

    .underline-indicators > *:hover,
    .underline-indicators > *:focus {
        border-color: black;
    }

    .underline-indicators > .active {
        border-color: black;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="underline.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="underline-indicators">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">00</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">01</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">02</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I edited your code so we have a working example here on Stack Overflow. What is the problem, cause I have the underline when I hover ?

Comment: Ok I see the underline in this example so perhaps it's my browser not working properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you gave us it doesn't work. But if you add `<!DOCTYPE html>` as Doctype declaration before the `<html>` tag, it works fine. The code snippet works, because in the iframe the Doctype is added. I guess, the CSS can't validate without it.

https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype